# Making SOAP Clients more fault tolerant when using class mapping

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a PHP wrapper for a SOAP service and using the class map option so I can work with objects instead of arrays. This works great until the provider of the SOAP service decides to add a new property to one of their objects (which they seem to like doing without telling anyone) at which point the SOAP client breaks with the error `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'NewlyAddedProperty' property` as there's now a property in the wsdl that isn't in the class.

I've tried to work around it by using a magic getter and returning things like `false`, `null` etc but as they're not valid values according to the wsdl it still throws up a fatal error.

In an ideal world the client would just set that new property on the object even if there isn't a property defined on the class, is that possible? If not just suppressing the error would also be fine.

Comment: The class map should not cause the SOAP encoding error. Possible culprit could be cached WSDL - try flushing the WSDL cache, fetch new WSDL from the provider and see if the problem persists.

Comment: that doesn't fix it unfortunately, the problem seems to be that the WSDL requires certain values for the new field type. With the field missing it defaults to `''` which isn't a valid option, so it errors out.

Comment: __get() magic method will not help because SOAP won't ask variables but rather uses var_export() or similar (internal function). And this problem is not with PHP - you'd get same situation with Java. The only way is to solve is set up concrete rules to trigger error which notifies you when WSDL changes, so you could adjust your classes and add that missing param.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `SoapClient`'s class mapping and use another one, eg [jsonmapper](https://github.com/netresearch/jsonmapper).

If your classes are annotated correctly, it's as simple as this example:

```
class noBisnodePersonClient extends SoapClient {

    // ...

    /**
     * sokPerson
     * @param noBisnodePersonSok $PersonSokReq
     * @return noBisnodePersonSokResponse
     */
    public function sokPerson(noBisnodePersonSok $PersonSokReq){
        $return = $this->__soapCall(
            'sokPerson',
            array($PersonSokReq),
            array('uri'=>'http://dbonline.no/webservices/wsdl/PersonInfo')
        );
        $mapper = new JsonMapper();
        $object = $mapper->map($return, new noBisnodePersonSokResponse);
        return $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there another option? I'd rather not re-write a load of code unless it's absolutely necessary

Comment: I added an example ilustrating it's not that difficult. You can even extend `__soapCall()` to add 6th paramter, class to return.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP means XML over HTTP - the owner of the SOAP service cannot and should not know all the systems calling it.

This brittleness is built into the SOAP interface.  The service should validate incoming requests against its schema.  It'll fail unless they make that path optional.  There's no 'duck typing' built in.